# Error while creating a menu in Python using TkInter. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, runtime-error

I'm having an error while creating a menu in Python using Tkinter. What am I doing wrong? My code and complete error traceback are given below.

**My code:**

```py
from tkinter import *
    
    
root = Tk()
root.title("FoodU")
root.geometry("1600x2560+0+0")


#main BEGIN
    
main = Frame(root, bg="light coral")
main.pack(fill=BOTH)
    
#main END
    
    
#navigation BEGIN
    
navigation = Frame(main, bg="floral white")
navigation.grid(padx=20)
    
    
nav = Menu(navigation)
navigation.config(menu=nav)
    
    
navcuisine = Menu(nav)
nav.add_casacde(label="Cuisines", menu=navcuisine)
navcuisine.add_command(label="Indian")
navcuisine.add_command(label="Chinese")
navcuisine.add_command(label="Japanese")
navcuisine.add_command(label="Italian")
navcuisine.add_command(label="Thai")
    
    
#navigation END
    
root.mainloop()
```

**The error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <file path>, line 52, in <module>
    navigation.config(menu=nav)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1482, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1473, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-menu"
```

What does this error mean? What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
navigation = Frame(main, bg="floral white")
navigation.grid(padx=20)


nav = Menu(navigation)
navigation.config(menu=nav)
```

This is a problem. Frame objects do not support the `menu` configuration option. As far as I know, only Toplevel widgets allow `menu`. One possible solution is to make `nav` a menu of `root` instead.

```
nav = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=nav)
```

Additionally, `nav.add_casacde(label="Cuisines", menu=navcuisine)` misspells "cascade". Try `nav.add_cascade(label="Cuisines", menu=navcuisine)` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped!